# Stop VS from automatically opening the folder for the active item

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, solution-explorer

Just wondering if anyone knows how to stop VS from automatically opening the folder for the active item. On my work computer it does this but my install doesn't, but I can't find the setting that I need to change.

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess: It may be related to the Track Active Item in Solution Explorer option:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> (General) -> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer