# How to avoid automatically unfolding of projects in Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have all the projects in a solution folded, so you can't see their files in the Solution Explorer. And a file belonging to one of those projects open. Once I browse to that file pane, the project containing the file is automatically unfolded in the Solution Explorer.

Is there a way to avoid that automatic unfolding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop VS from automatically opening the folder for the active item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056667/stop-vs-from-automatically-opening-the-folder-for-the-active-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but in the VS 2010 options, under "Projects and Solutions/General" there is an option called "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer".

I've just tried unchecking that and, with a mutiple project solution all collapsed, when clicking into an open code file it doesn't open up the project in the solution window. Try that and see if it produces the result you're after.

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question though!

Comment: This is exactly what he's looking for. Turn off "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer". The most annoying setting ever invented. At least for us OCD folks.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm glad it's not just me that finds that setting irritating!

Comment: +1 for voting that setting as terribly annoying. Thanks! It was exactly what I was after.